# Laravel route group prefix - variable not working

Tags: laravel, variables, routes, prefix

**in web.php :**

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['checklang','checkmoney']],function(){
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/'.session()->get('lang'));
    });
    
    Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'where'=>['locale'=>'[a-zA-Z]{2}']],
 function() {

    Route::get('/tour/{id}','HomeController@getTours');
});
});
```

**in HomeContoller :**

```
   public function getTours($id){
 
    dd($id);
}
```

when trying to access url : example.com/en/tour/5
getting result
`en` , but should be `5`

Where is a problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Your route has 2 variables, `{locale}` and `{id}`, but your Controller method is only referencing one of them. You need to use both:

`web.php`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function () {
  ...
  Route::get('/tour/{id}', 'HomeController@getTours');
});
```

`HomeController.php`

```
public function getTours($locale, $id) {
   dd($locale, $id); // 'en', 5
}
```

Note: The order of definition matters; `{locale}` (en) comes before `{id}` 5, so make sure you define them in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, I tried it before to make this question, for some reason it was not working, but now when I retried it it's OK. Thanks a lot.